# Retrieving the value from a Selenium Webdriver WebElement field and passing it to a java variable

Tags: java, class, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Firstly, forgive the beginner question.  I'm a relative newcomer to both Java and Selenium Webdriver.

I am learning Webdriver through trying to test a CMS application.  The CMS has the concept of creating articles and sending them through a workflow. So, an editor might create an article and send through to a SuperUser.  So, I am creating an article as an editor and am populating the 'Title' field by using sendKeys text and appending the date of creation:

```
public class EditorArticleCreator {

    private static WebDriver driver;
    private static String baseURL = TestEnv.getUrl();
    static WebDriverWait wait;
    Date date = new Date();
    static String articleName;

    public static String getArticleName(){
        return articleName;
    }

//some code and then:

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Article_Title")).sendKeys("New_Article_" + date.toString());
```

What I want to do is pass the String value of the created Title into a variable that I can then retrieve in the class of the SuperUser (via a Get method).

```
public class EditArticleSuperUser {

    EditorArticleCreator.getArticleName();

}
```

This way, I hope that when I have WebDriver login as the SuperUser, they will pick the correct article as the full String will be stored in the articleName field.

Is this the best way?  How would I get the String value from the driver.findElement?

Comment: You're looking for the element.getText() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use getAttribute to get the value attribute of the text input:

```
WebElement articleTitleField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Article_Title"));
articleTitleField.sendKeys("New_Article_" + date.toString());
articleName = articleTitleField.getAttribute("value");
```

Or MrTi's suggestion of articleTitleField.getText() would work too!

Comment: Thanks.  What would be the best way of passing the value of articleName into the other class?  I have a getter method as you can see and then in the EditArticleSuperUser class I now have the following: 

public static String articleName = EditorArticleCreator.getArticleName();                                                                                                 then,  WebElement newarticle = driver.findElement(By.linkText(articleName));
        assertEquals("finds new article", articleName, newarticle.getText()); However,error I get is "Cannot find elements when link text is null."

Answer (score 0):

Why not store your title in a String variable `articleName` first, and then use `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Article_Title")).sendKeys(articleName)` to populate the name of the Article's Title. Then reference this `articleName` variable later when you want to verify it was posted appropriately.