# Java: passing a value from one class to another using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, class, selenium, scope, webdriver

I recently asked this question:
[Retrieving the value from a Selenium Webdriver WebElement field and passing it to a java variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797626/retreiving-the-value-from-a-selenium-webdriver-webelement-field-and-passing-it-t)

So I implemented the accepted answer which allowed me to (or so I thought), pass the value of the string into a variable (articleName). What I then wanted to do, was to pass this variable into the next class so that the SuperUser could find the article *by the string articleName* and then use it (there are many articles in the SuperUser's dashboard).

However, the message I receive is: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find elements when link text is null.
    at org.openqa.selenium.By.linkText(By.java:63)

Clearly, I am not passing the value in correctly.  I may be racing ahead of myself here as I am a beginner so, if someone could explain the basic premise of my mistake I'd be very grateful!  Code snippets below:

//Class #1

```
public class EditorArticleCreator {

private static WebDriver driver;
public static String baseURL = TestEnv.getUrl();
public static String username = User.getUsernameEditor();
public static String password = User.getPasswordEditor();
static WebDriverWait wait;
static Date date = new Date();
public static String articleName;

public static String getArticleName(){
    return articleName;
}
```

//some code and then....

```
    WebElement articleTitleField =driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Article_Title"));
    articleTitleField.sendKeys("Editor_Feature_Article_" + date.toString());
    articleName = articleTitleField.getText();
```

//Class #2

```
public class EditArticleSuperUser {

private static WebDriver driver;
public static String baseURL = TestEnv.getUrl();
public static String username = User.getUsernameSuperUser();
public static String password = User.getPasswordSuperUser();
static WebDriverWait wait;
public static String articleName = EditorArticleCreator.getArticleName();
```

//some code and then.....

```
    WebElement newarticle = driver.findElement(By.linkText(articleName));
    assertEquals("finds new article", articleName, newarticle.getText());
```

Comment: `(By.linkText(articleName));`.... `articleName` is `null` then. You need to debug this. What gets returned from `articleTitleField.getText();` ...? What kind of element is it?

Comment: In the middle block of code, that code must be in the `EditorArticleCreator`, the *test* cannot declare a `String articleName`, *and* that test must have run before the test in Class 2.  Is all of that true?

Comment: If `articleName` is `static` then you don't need to do `EditorArticleCreator.getArticleName()`, just do `EditorArticleCreator.articleName`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed reply.  Arran - 'null' is returned from articleTitleField.getText(); though I'm unsure why.  Mr Ti - I *think* all of what you say is true.  There is undoubtedly a simpler and more elegant way of doing this.  Essentially, I simply want to create a new article title with the date appended, pass this into a field then have Test 2 (seperate class in same package) access the String so it can interrogate the DOM and find the article by the name.

Comment: This needs to be debugged. You also have *everything* as `static` which is going to be forming the base of the issue. Why are you doing that?